# How do i maintain the width responsiveness on card image Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[image: Demo]

New to CSS please bear with me. I'm trying to implement responsive images contained within a `card`. Initially when its 6 images on same row, it's all working as intended, i.e the images width are 100% of the card and they are all vertically aligned in middle regardless of the different image sizes.

Facing issues when I adjust the screen size, instead of maintaining a 100% width(of card) and vertically aligning all images in the middle, current behaviour as demonstrated in GIF above is the images float to the top of the card and the width is no longer 100%.

This is bootstrap, here is how my image class looks:

```
.card-img-top {
  height: 10vw
  object-fit: contain
}
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT** The code

```html
<div class="row">
  <div-class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 mt-4">
    <div class="card>
      <img width="100%" src="https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/mpsAAOSw9T9c~j93/s-l225.webp" class="card-img-top">
      <div class="card-body" style="text-align: center";>
        <div class="car-body-wrapper cards-body">
          <h6 class="card-subtitle">
            <a href="#foo" style="color: rgb(0, 172, 230);">BMW X3</a> 
          </h6><p class="card-text"> </p></div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ... //same for other 5 images
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason for giving height: 10vw, because height will vary when the dev-tools dock is opened.

Comment: Can you include all the relevant code?

Comment: @Darth I think you can use CSS media queries for responsive design.

Comment: @Zim See EDIT for all the code

Comment: @VivekrajKR Used the `height` so that all the text  ie `card-subtitle` are horizontally aligned for all cards

Comment: Great use of animated image to explain the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following code may help you, you can take image hight in pixel according to your website need. If anything goes wrong again then notify me. I will check.

```
<style>
   .card-img-top {
     height: 150px;
     width:100%;
    object-fit: contain;
  } 
</style>


<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 mt-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/mpsAAOSw9T9c~j93/s-l225.webp" class="card-img-top">
      <div class="card-body" style="text-align: center";>
      <div class="car-body-wrapper cards-body">
      <h6 class="card-subtitle">
        <a href="#foo" style="color: rgb(0, 172, 230);">BMW X3</a> 
      </h6><p class="card-text"> </p></div> 
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

Comment: @Darth  Ok fine..  :)

Answer (score 0):

for the responsive image size you can use CSS media queries. You can put your CSS code inside the media queries. Following code will help you.

```
<style>

/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {  

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

  }

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {  

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {  

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

} 
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep,  have tried to set the image width to 100% for all screen sizes but its not working?